# Is it possible to install the .Net Framework partially?

Tags: .net

I'm writing pretty simple application that maybe is only couple of megabytes. I don't want to make the end user download 20 or more MB of framework. What to do? Is it possible to load only assemblies that I need, jit and all the things necessary for .net application?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing that provides a per-assembly level of granular control, unfortunately.

However, if you're using .NET 3.5 or 4 (in VS 2010), you can use the new [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx), which only includes assemblies for Client apps (WPF, Forms, WCF, etc).

Comment: As I can see the only installer has small size (868 KB) but itself framework is much more (41 MB).

Comment: That's the way it goes. You don't have many options beyond the Client Profile, like it or not. So, to reiterate, the answer to your question is use Client Profile or stick with the entire framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly distribute the framework piecemeal, but you should take a look at the [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx). You should also consult [SmallestDotNet](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/) which provides online and offline installer options and suggestions.

Comment: Sure 300 MB is much but 40 MB is too much too. Because usually the simple application doesn't use of assemblies, only several of them, so it seems to stupid to download the whole framework.

Comment: You saw the NET 4 Client Profile RTM Web Bootstrapper option, yes?